# Rocket.Chat websocket is disabled for this server

Tags: android, ios, docker, nginx, rocket.chat

I recently set up a rocket.chat instance on my Server via docker. Everything is working fine in browser and mac app, but not on android or ios mobile app.

After I type in the workplace url I am getting the message "Websocket is disabled on this server".

The server:

- Ubuntu 22.04 LTS
- Powered by Plesk 18.0.50
- NodeJS 18

I strictly followed all configurations and hints on different posts, but nothing did the trick. My nginx config:

```
location ~ ^/.* {
    proxy_pass https://chat.my-domain.de:3000;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection $connection_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
    proxy_set_header X-Nginx-Proxy true;
    proxy_redirect off;
}
```

I have no more ideas how to solve it, do you have any tips? Thanks a lot!

Comment: i think rocket chat is not serious about solving developers issues. I have also read the documentation and nothing is there about websocket.